# Is the Chorleywood bread making process broadly used outside the UK

Tags: bread

The Chorleywood bread making process is an industrial bread making technique which results in a soft, fluffy loaf.

According to Wikipedia, “As of 2009, 80% of bread made in the United Kingdom used the process.” But from what I could see there was not an account of how common the process is outside the UK.

**How commonly used is thhe Chorleywood process outside of the UK?**

Perhaps I am mistaken, but I associate the process with very light, soft bread, the kind often called ‘toast bread’ in Europe. From my experience in Germany only 5% of the bread sold in supermarkets is of this type, so it may be rarely or never used.

Comment: I'm not finding any evidence that it's used in the USA.  Since it started out as a way to use soft British wheat instead of higher-protein American wheat, it would make sense that it's never been used there.  However, it's hard to find evidence of absence.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's only used in Britain. I'm not a native, and often wondered why the bread was indigestible and tasteless, compared to the delicious bread from Ireland, France Germany...
Recently, discussed the isssue with a local Italian. On explaining the Chorleywood method they were astounded... in my experience, the majority of the public are unaware of the process too, as most grow up eating this inferior 'bread'.  Additionally, due to the process some mistakenly think, that they're gluten intolerant.
Years ago, I recall Delia Smith dismissing it, as she pulled the centre out of a loaf and rolled it up in her hand like a ball of putty! Hence on the occasion that I've eaten it, it's always been toasted, i.e.cooked!

Comment: It's not only used in the UK - it's definitely used in Australia, India and New Zealand, probably South Africa also. I suspect Canada and the USA use it or very similar process too, I can't find any evidence to support this other than the texture and taste of the mass-produced breads there.